# French Long Stay Visa Tracking in India

Tags: france, student-visa

I had applied for my French student/long stay Visa in India earlier this month (biometrics on 4th). I did pay for the sms and e-mail updates, though I have received none to date. Upon using the website link for tracking applications, I was informed that it was forwarded to the appropriate consulate on the 6th of July.

I have not heard anything from the VFS or had any change in the update. What should I do to find out the status or is it just enough to wait and have the courier come home one fine day?

Comment: When I was in this situation there wasn't much I could do besides wait and check my email all the time. My visa was late and I started work 3 weeks late as a consequence. I was finally able to call them and get a human on the phone after a lot of effort, but this was in the UK so YMMV.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique: even though this could vary by country of application, that's comforting, to be honest. I applied well ahead of time so that I could account for an unforeseen delay. I need to get going only by the end of next month, but it's still a bit unsettling to know that there's no update via e-mail or sms even after signing up for it.

Comment: The email / SMS thing probably means that they will send you an email and SMS to let you know that your passport is ready. They actually do not process long stay visas in-country; they are sent to France, which takes additional time, and so the processing centre won't have any information for you until they get it back from France. If you already got to the point where your stuff was sent, I don't think you'll be denied. There are just sometimes delays with these things. There was another post here where an OP had good results by getting their university/lab to contact the French govt.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique: I didn't know the long stay visas weren't processed in-country! They usually give a 20-25 day timeframe on their website, so I was expecting it to be done pronto.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique if you would add an answer using your comments, I'll upvote.

Comment: @Dorothy Answer added.

Answer (score 1):

Opening disclaimer: This answer is based on personal experience and things I was told at the time, which was in the UK, not from India, and was for a different long-stay visa than yours.

At the time, my long-stay visa was very delayed. I was told that there is nothing I could do besides wait. In my case I started work about 3 weeks late. They will email or text (if you sign up for this option) you when your passport is ready to be collected, and they will not specify whether the visa is accepted or rejected. You find that out when collecting your passport, which in my case could be done in person or in the post.

If you're really in a pinch, check whether the website you used to start your application has a 'Contact Us' page. You can send an email and request that they call you. They will, sometimes, call you back after that.

NB: I was told by the agent that long-stay visas are sent to France (Nantes, IIRC) and processed there. So at some point, to the company, the process becomes a 'black box' and they won't know anything once it's sent, until it arrives back. Note also that the month of August is very slow in France, if you're aiming for around this time.

Another poster on this SE had good results getting their university/lab to contact the visa office, but they were a researcher, so this may be less of a valid option for you.

If you have gotten to this point already, I would imagine it's quite unlikely that you will be denied. The company has already vetted your application, so it's looking good.

Bonne chance!